# Prolonging the admin session

Tags: magento2, admin, session

I'm working on a Magento 2 module that may require a lot of form filling in the backend that in some cases may cause the session to expire.
I want to avoid this.
I know that theoretically I can make an ajax call to any page every X seconds to prolong the session, but I want to do it right.
Is there already an action that does nothing else but prolonging the session or do I have to create one?
Or is there an other way to prevent the session from expiring only when on a specific admin page?

Comment: `persistent_session_expired` event gonna help out?

Comment: Can't you make you `session.gc_maxlifetime` higher?

Comment: I plan to distribute this extension and I cannot control every environment where this is installed. I want to avoid people complaining that they spent 20 minutes filling in a form just to have the session expired.

Comment: I see, it makes sense. I might be wrong, but I think that your solution is kind of what Prestashop is doing in the admin, there are regular calls to an Ajax script with yields current order counts, customer counts ... etc

Comment: I have no idea what prestashop does (my ecommerce is the only true ecommerce :D ). But this solution seams simple and easy to implement anywhere it is needed.

Comment: Shots were  fired ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something that prolongs the session in [`\Magento\Setup\Controller\Session::prolongAction()`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Controller/Session.php#L50) but it's only for the setup wizard.
So I stopped looking and built my own.
I my module I added a new controller action:

```
namespace [Namespace]\[Module]\Controller\Adminhtml\[Entity];

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

class Prolong extends Action
{
    /**
     * prolong session
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(json_encode(['success' => true]));
    }
}
```

Then created a simple block and template that can be included in any page.

```
namespace [Namespace]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template;

class SessionProlong extends Template
{
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSessionProlongUrl()
    {
        return $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl('[module]/[controller]/prolong');
    }
}
```

and the template `session_prolong.phtml`:

```
<?php /** @var \[Namespace]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\SessionProlong $block */ ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["jquery"],
        function(jQuery) {
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                setInterval(function(){
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: '<?php /** @noEscape */ echo $block->getSessionProlongUrl() ?>'
                    });
                }, 60000)
            });
        }
    );
</script>
```

The block can now be added in any admin page through the layout file:

```
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="[Namespace]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\SessionProlong" name="session_prolong" template="[Namespace]_[Module]::session_prolong.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

When the block and template is present in the page, an AJAX call will be made ever 60 seconds to my controller action, that does nothing else than prolonging the session.
I left the browser open over night and I didn't get logged out, so I can conclude it works.

Comment: Not working, got ajaxExpired: 1 error in response. and admin session timeout.